# Share Url on facebook

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to share on facebook in my asp.net mvc when i use this code i got error in face window

in my view

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>


 function fbs_click() {
        u = location.href; t = document.title; window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: URL :     https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61231%2Fen%2FTraineeArea%2FExamsAnswers%2FTraineeExam&t=Center

Sorry, something went wrong.

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Go back

Comment: thank it now working